# How to use the data matrix to fit the specific 2D-function in matlab

Tags: matlab, data-fitting

Provided that I have the 5*5 dataArray

```
    d=    [0.0177104427823448,0.00246661459209512,0.0399831543374395,0.0615494164555707,0.0476204124707652;0.0275276152854314,0.0219153841813084,0.0581144391404502,0.144890028400954,0.157839631316098;0.0622883972729130,0.0716157303159909,0.245482781674067,0.123999612575059,0.177495187746408;0.0200735764542146,0.0573087934038160,0.0636451189717613,0.0160810084568415,0.0484992279558924;0.0185180386159227,0.00841167700273800,0.0372017422726281,0.0173721095082637,0.0459520362441099]
```

And I want to use the data to fit the specific 2D-function with a least-square fitting technique. The function is like this:

```
    r = alfa*sin(pi*(n1+delta1))*sin(pi*(n2+delta2)) / (25*sin(pi/5*(n1+delta1))*sin(pi/5*(n2+delta2))),
```

where alfa,delta1,delta2 are the parameters that need to be estimated, and n1,n2 range from 1 to 5.

The function fitting result will be like this:
[image]

I don't know how to do these things in MATLAB. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have the curve fitting toolbox? If you do then `lsqnonlin` is your best bet. Otherwise maybe have a look at `fmincon`

Comment: Yeah,I do have.But can `lsqnonlin` solve the 2D-function fitting problem? @Dan

Comment: Sure, it takes a little manipulation though: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/238630

Comment: Well,I've implemented the function fitting procedure folowing the website you posted and I've posted the code as an answer to my question.But the result is not so good cause there should be a peak in the final result, while the fitting data is more smooth than the original data! @Dan

Comment: And I also want the fitting result can be more precision.For excemple,now I have the 5*5 data array as the original data,and I want a 25*25 array as the fitting result.To be more clearly,you can see the pictiure I posted,where the black dot is the original data array and the function fitting accuracy can reach 0.2. @Dan

Comment: Try and interpolate your 5x5 matrix before the fitting?

Comment: From more specific to more general: `lsqcurvefit` < `lsqnonlin` < `fmincon`. It's probably better to try the more specific method first, although `fmincon` implements several algorithms to choose from that are not listed for `lsqcurvefit`.

Comment: This is a must-skim before choosing a solver: http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/optim/ug/choosing-a-solver.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,thanks to @Dan.My question seems to be implemented like this:

```
[n,m]=size(d);%assumes that d is a n x m matrix
[X,Y]=meshgrid(1:n,1:m);%your x-y coordinates
x(:,1)=X(:); % x= first column
x(:,2)=Y(:); % y= second column
f=d(:); % your data f(x,y) (in column vector)

%--- now define the function in terms of x
%--- where you use x(:,1)=X and x(:,2)=Y
fun = @(c,x) c(1)*sin(pi*(x(:,1)+c(2))).*sin(pi*(x(:,2)+c(3))) ./ (25*sin(pi/5*(x(:,1)+c(2))).*sin(pi/5*(x(:,2)+c(3))));

%--- now solve with lsqcurvefit
options=optimset('TolX',1e-6);
c0=[1 0 0];%start-guess here
cc=lsqcurvefit(fun,c0,x,f,[],[],options);
Ifit=fun(cc,x); 
Ifit=reshape(Ifit,[n m]);%fitting data reshaped as matrix
surf(X,Y,Ifit);
hold on;
plot3(X, Y, dataArray);
```